# C++ vector<> to QML to bind barseries values

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am making a little project to connect a ESP8266 directly to an android App.

The general view is that I am storing a series of sensors readings on the ESP and, reading them using a C++ class. After that I pass these values as a `list<int>` to the QML code.

Up to this point, everything works fine. I am able to send and print the values at the QML end. However, when I feed them into a barseries.values property it doesnt work.

For the sake of simplicity I will demonstrate the problem with a fixed `list<int>`.

C++ method into ApplicationData:

```
std::vector<int> ApplicationData::getlast12hours(void)
{
    std::vector<int> myList = {1,3,3,4,5,6,10,12,30,45,55,12};
    return myList;
}
```

c++ main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQuickView view;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    ApplicationData data;
    view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("applicationData", &data);
    view.setSource(url);
    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
MainForm {
      //somecode
      OperationForm
      {
              property var myarray:applicationData.getlast24hours()
              property var mytest:[1,3,3,4,5,6,10,12,30,45,55,12]
              bs_hist12h.values: [myarray[0],myarray[1],myarray[2],myarray[3],myarray[4],myarray[5],myarray[6],myarray[7],myarray[8],myarray[9],myarray[10],myarray[11]]
      }
      //somecode
}
```

Now here is the problem; when I set bs_hist12h.values:myarray, it does not work. But when I set just as above, it works. And when I set it as bs_hist12h.values:mytest, it also works. The funny thing is that when I debug, myarray and mytest are exactly the same object. Actually, the way I am doing solves the problem, but in a very ugly manner. I wonder if is there a more sophisticated approach.

Finally, the operationform.ui.qml

```
//some code
ChartView {
//some code
    BarSeries {
        name: "BarSeries"
        axisX: BarCategoryAxis { categories: ["00","01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11"]} 
        BarSet {
            id: bs_hist12h
            }
//somecode
    }
}
//somecode
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Use QVector instead `std::vector`

Comment: same thing... it passes to the KML but not to the barset.

Comment: Doesn't it throw you an error? bs_hist12h is only visible in operationform.ui.qml and not in main.qml (the id has a valid scope only in the .qml where it was defined), you have to export that property.

Comment: cpp: `ApplicationData::getlast12hours(void)`  qml: `applicationData.getlast24hours()`?

Comment: add `property alias bs_hist12h: bs_hist12h` after `ChartView{`

Comment: "Doesn't it throw you an error? bs_hist12h is only visible in operationform.ui.qml and not in main.qml " : (answer: i have implemented the alias bs_hist12h at the main.qml, so it does not throw any error).
add property alias bs_hist12h: bs_hist12h (i missed to inform, i had this property after the item definition at the operationform.ui.qml. I have tried change its place as you have suggested but it throws the error:
qrc:/main.qml:31:21: Cannot assign to non-existent property "bs_hist12h" 
                         bs_hist12h.values: myarray/

Comment: I think the problem is that maybe there is a difference between myarray and mytest that i am not noticing. The communication between c++ and QML are working. When I stop the debug after the initialization of both, they are defined (in the QML side) as objects, and both have exactly the same value. So I dont understand why passing mytest works and myarray doesn't.